# concatenate fields in the case fields into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query to find all the fields that has 'nan' into it  and have to show which fields have this value record by record . Any suggestions

```
select Lastname, Firstname, Middle_Name__c ,MailingCity,Mailingstreet,Email,Parent1_FirstName,Parent1_LastName,Parent1_Email,  Parent2_FirstName,Parent2_LastName, parent2_email,
      case
       when  LastName like '%nan%'  then LastName  else ' 'end 'lastname_Imapcted'
      ,case when  FirstName like '%nan%' then FirstName else ' '  end 'Firstname_Imapcted'
      ,case when Middle_Name__c like '%nan%' then  Middle_Name__c else ' ' end 'MiddleName_Imapcted' 
      ,case when  MailingCity like '%nan%'  then MailingCity else ' ' end 'MailingCity_Imapcted'
  ,case when  Email like '%nan%' then  Email else ' ' end 'Email_Imapcted'
,case  when  Parent1_FirstName like '%nan%'then  Parent1_FirstName else ' ' end 'Parent1_Firstname_Imapcted'
 ,case when  Parent1_LastName like '%nan%' then Parent1_LastName else ' ' end 'Parent1lastname_Imapcted'
 ,case when  Parent1_Email like'%nan%' then  Parent1_email else ' ' end 'Parent1email_Imapcted'
 ,case when  Parent2_Email like '%nan%' then Parent2_email else ' ' end 'Parent2email_Imapcted'
 ,case when  Parent2_FirstName like '%nan%' then Parent2_firstname else ' ' end 'Parent2firstname_Imapcted'
 ,case when   Parent2_LastName like '%nan%'then  parent2_lastname else ' ' end 'Parent2lastname_Imapcted '
 ,case when   MailingStreet like '%nan%' then  MailingStreet else ' ' end 'Mailingstreet_Imapcted'
 ,concat(Parent1_Firstname_Imapcted,Parent2lastname_Imapcted) as 'Impacted Fields'
   from RE_Data_Sandbox..Temp_ADB_Student_Roster_ALL_06092017
     where LastName like '%nan%'
 or FirstName like '%nan%'
 or Middle_Name__c like '%nan%'
 or MailingCity like '%nan%'
 or Email like '%nan%'
 or Parent1_FirstName like '%nan%'
 or Parent1_LastName like '%nan%'
 or Parent1_Email like'%nan%'
 or Parent2_Email like '%nan%'
 or Parent2_FirstName like '%nan%'
 or Parent2_LastName like '%nan%'
 or MailingStreet like '%nan%'
```

Answer (score 1):

first off the where clause can be re-written as

```
where concat(LastName,FirstName,Middle_Name__c,MailingCity,Email,Parent1_FirstName,Parent1_LastName,Parent1_Email,Parent2_Email,Parent2_FirstName,Parent2_LastName,MailingStreet) like '%nan%'
```

and your select fields should just work fine or better use IIF

```
IIF ( LastName like '%nan%',LastName,'') 'lastname_Imapcted'
,IIF(  FirstName like '%nan%',FirstName,'')'Firstname_Imapcted'
,IIF( Middle_Name__c like '%nan%', Middle_Name__c ,'') 'MiddleName_Imapcted' 
,IIF(  MailingCity like '%nan%',MailingCity ,'') 'MailingCity_Imapcted'
  ,IIF(  Email like '%nan%', Email ,'') 'Email_Imapcted'
,IIF  Parent1_FirstName like '%nan%'then  Parent1_FirstName ,'') 'Parent1_Firstname_Imapcted'
 ,IIF(  Parent1_LastName like '%nan%',Parent1_LastName ,'') 'Parent1lastname_Imapcted'
 ,IIF(  Parent1_Email like'%nan%', Parent1_email ,'') 'Parent1email_Imapcted'
 ,IIF(  Parent2_Email like '%nan%',Parent2_email ,'') 'Parent2email_Imapcted'
 ,IIF(  Parent2_FirstName like '%nan%',Parent2_firstname ,'') 'Parent2firstname_Imapcted'
 ,IIF(   Parent2_LastName like '%nan%'then  parent2_lastname ,'') 'Parent2lastname_Imapcted '
 ,IIF(   MailingStreet like '%nan%', MailingStreet ,'') 'Mailingstreet_Imapcted'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get a list of fields just by concatenating the strings.  If you want a comma-delimited list:

```
select stuff((case when LastName like '%nan%' then ',LastName' else '' end) + 
             (case when FirstName like '%nan%' then ',FirstName' else '' end) + 
             (case when Middle_Name__c like '%nan%' then ',Middle_Name__c' else '' end) + 
             (case when MailingCity like '%nan%' then ',MailingCity' else '' end) + 
             . . .
             (case when MailingStreet like '%nan%' then ',MailingStreet' else '' end),
             1, 1, '')
. . .
```

The `stuff()` just handles the commas so the list looks more "normal".